# Skip thread instructions in Xcode Debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

When I try to find out which line of code causes the app to crash with setting some breakpoints and using `Step in` command, I often come to some thread instructions (I don't know how this is called). I can only see numbers combined with letters there and want to skip all this to the next line of code. If I use `Continue program execution` the app crashes and so I am not sure which line caused the crash.

I can't manually go over each thread instruction because there is really a lot of them. I tried using some other commands, for example `Step over instruction` and `Step over thread` in the Debug menu, but apparently this only instructs Xcode to skip the current thread instruction and go to the next, which gives me the same result as using the `Step in` command.

I have watched tutorials about debugging but none of them mentioned what to do in this case. I also have troubles googling about the topic because I don't know how this is even called.

I am sorry my explanation of what I want to know is really bad, but I really don't know how else I could describe it. If you do understand what I mean, please tell me what this is and how I can skip it or understand what it is doing.

Comment: Does "step out" when you first see instructions get you back to your code?

Comment: Please show a screen shot. The notion that you don't know which line is causing the crash is really where you should be focusing your question. I'm curious as to how you can fail to know this.

Comment: I added a screenshot. No, it does not get me back to my code, it stays in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Most times, you may want to use 'step over' in order to walk through your own code one line at a time. This action will take you to the next line of code in the current method, or if at the end of the method, then take you to the place that called the current method.

Use 'step in' in order to go to the next line that will be executed, which may involve going to method implementation details, which could be either your code, or library code, or framework code, or system code. If you get to code that you don't care about, then use 'step out' until you are back to debugging code that you do care about.

Having said that... when you do get a crash, then Xcode should already be providing you with a stacktrace in the log output that says exactly where the crash occurred.. =/

Sidenote: Adding log statements can be helpful. And, using a crash analytics library like Crashlytics can also be extremely helpful.